# How to get the traits details of a specific NFT id?

Tags: nft, erc-721

How to get the traits and the metadata of specific NFTs by its token id?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Moralis NFT API to get that.

Here is an example step-by-step: https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/how-to-get-the-metadata-of-an-nft

Let me know if you need any help!

Here is how an expected result looks like

```
{
  "token_address": "0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb",
  "token_id": "3931",
  "transfer_index": [
    13868997,
    30,
    36,
    0
  ],
  "owner_of": "0x1cf2b8c64aed32bff2ae80e701681316d3212afd",
  "block_number": "13868997",
  "block_number_minted": "5754322",
  "token_hash": "3c86855c82470edd82df190019e83f16",
  "amount": "1",
  "contract_type": null,
  "name": "CRYPTOPUNKS",
  "symbol": "Ͼ",
  "token_uri": "https://www.larvalabs.com/cryptopunks/details/3931",
  "metadata": "{\"image\":\"https://www.larvalabs.com/cryptopunks/cryptopunk3931.webp\",\"name\":\"CryptoPunk 3931\",\"attributes\":[\"Vampire Hair\",\"Goat\"],\"description\":\"Male\"}",
  "last_token_uri_sync": null,
  "last_metadata_sync": "2022-05-12T18:00:22.340Z",
  "minter_address": "0xc352b534e8b987e036a93539fd6897f53488e56a"
}
```

Disclosure: I work at Moralis